# Order of an element in $U(13)$ and $U(7)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is a fact that in $U(13)$, the order of $12$ is $|12|=2$ and in $U(7)$, the order of $6$ is $|6|=2$.

But I don't understand why.

What I am trying is this:

$(12)(12) = 144 \equiv_{13} 1$ so the order should be 1... can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: See the answer below by Mr @Azif00, you need to find $k$. In your case, $12^2=1$ and hence $|12|=2$

Comment: Note that $12\equiv-1\bmod13$ and $6\equiv-1\bmod7$, and $-1\not\equiv1$, but $(-1)^2=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of an element $a$ in $U(n)$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. With this, note that $12 \not\equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ but $12^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$, so, the order of $12$ is in fact $2$.

Comment: I see. Thank you